# Embedding a binary tree on a Poincaré disc

Tags: graph-theory, trees, hyperbolic-geometry, graph-embeddings

Given a binary tree, with parent node $O$, and each node having two children. Is there a prescription for what the coordinates of each node will be if I want to embed the tree in a Poincaré disc such that node $O$ is at the origin?
Basically I want to construct an embedding that looks something like [this](https://dawn.cs.stanford.edu/assets/img/2018-03-19-hyperbolics/v2.png). Is there a simple equation for the $x,y$ coordinates of each node? Or a deterministic algorithm to calculate it?

Thanks!